# Which git workflow to use if develop and master cannot be synced

Tags: git, github

We have a repo to which multiple teams are working together. There are three branches - master, develop and feature branches. The master is in sync with the production environment and develop in sync with development environment. I am new to git and I want to understand what is the right git workflow here since develop and master cannot be synced - meaning all the changes in develop cannot go into master.

Suppose my team is working on a feature A, then should this branch be created on top of master and then first merged into develop. And if I want to move it into master, I will merge the same branch to master as well?

I have also been into a scenario where I have created a feature branch of master, made my changes, then when I tried to merge the PR to develop, I got merge conflicts, so I fixed the merge conflicts from Github which actually merged develop into my branch. So the problem now is when I try to merge this branch to master it will have all the commits from develop which is not what I want. Can someone help me understand this as well?

Comment: The master branch is meant for production env only, so you should never branch out from that branch, and instead, branch out from the develop branch. And after your feature is finished, you will merge the feature branch back to the develop branch.

And for the sync issue, as the develop branch is under active development. The branch will end up merging back into the master branch once a sprint or milestone is finished.

Comment: If you guys are using Git flow, one exception for branching out from the master branch would be to create a hotfix when a bug is encountered in the production app. The hotfix will be created from the master branch and once tested merge back to both master and develop branches to ensure the bug is fixed on both branches.

Comment: Regarding this: "all the changes in `develop` cannot go into `master`." How do you determine which changes can go into `master`? And, for the stuff in `develop` that you don't want to go into `master`, do you care about them or can you throw them away? If you care about them, is that because they will eventually go into `master`, or is the Dev environment supposed to be running different code than Prod, even if all code was perfectly prod ready?

Comment: @konekoya No, develop and master cannot be synced. This is because we have several teams and we cannot wait for one team if they are ready for release or not. And some changes are just for testing in development environment, they need not go to master

Comment: @TTT so we work on a feature branch and test in develop and if we want to move that to master then we can use that feature branch, right? And no, dev environment can run different code than prod. This is basically a data engineering project.

Comment: Regarding, "dev environment can run different code than prod", is that a *can*, or a *must*? If it's a "must" then it sounds like your Dev environment has two different purposes: 1.) Test code that "might" go into Prod, and 2.) Something else that requires(?) some code on `develop` that never will go into Prod. Instead, ideally you would have one environment that could be used only for testing code before it goes into Prod. That might be the Dev env or maybe a new env dedicated for that purpose. If you can do that, you can reset `develop` to equal `master` periodically to clean it up.

Comment: The workflow that Git uses, [gitworkflows](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows) would rename your `develop` branch to be `next` and periodically resets it to equal `master`. New features branch off of `master` and get merged into `next` for testing. After a while `next` gets bloated with stuff you aren't keeping, including older versions of stuff you fixed up before it was perfect, and you just blow it away and start fresh, perhaps timed with each release. But if you have stuff you need on `develop` that isn't in `master`, you can't do this- you need a third branch, or repo, or flag.

Comment: @TTT yes, I cannot recreate develop like that because of dependency with other teams. Some teams might need their changes in develop, some dont. Can you tell me if there is anything wrong with these steps? - 1) create feature branch of master 2) raise pr against develop 3) after its merged and tested raise PR with the same feature branch against master ? this way teams can work independently right?